# Apply event on combobox in datagridview cell . (DatagridViewColoumnComboBox)

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview, combobox

I am developing window apllication in c#. I want to apply "SelectedValuechanged" event on the combo box e , this combobox is inside the datagridview. I am unable to access the each combo-box in datagridviewcomboboxcoloumn.
Plz help me, how can i do it??

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can handle [DataGridView.EditingControlShowing Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing.aspx).

Code example:

```
    private void dataGridViewReadings_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox combobox = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (combobox != null)
        {
            combobox.SelectionChanged -= combobox_SelectionChanged;

            combobox.SelectionChanged += combobox_SelectionChanged;
        }
    }
```